# Incremental compilation in nvcc (CUDA)

Tags: gcc, compilation, cuda, nvcc, incremental-build

I have many structs (classes) and standalone functions that I like to compile separately and then link to the CUDA kernel, but I am getting the `External calls are not supported` error while compiling (not linking) the kernel. nvcc forces to always use inline functions from the kernel. This is very frustrating!! If somebody have figured out a way to achieve incremental compilation, please share.

Also see the following thread on NVIDIA forums.
http://forums.nvidia.com/index.php?s=&showtopic=103256&view=findpost&p=1009242

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently you cannot call device functions from the GPU in CUDA, which is why they are inlined.

[Fermi](http://www.nvidia.com/fermi) hardware supports device functions without inlining.

Comment: And as far as I know, inline functions cannot be linked from object file. Right?

Comment: No, you'll need the next gen for that too.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it can now be done with CUDA 5.